# How to force ROS compressed_image_transport to use libturbojpeg for jpeg compression?

Tags: jpeg, ros, turbojpeg

In my Jetson Xavier, a see 'libjpegturbo' library is available. How can I make compressed_image_transport plugin to use 'turbojpeg' library for good compression level.

Below is a snapchot of `ldconfig`..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the implementation of *compressed_publisher.cpp* at [GitHub](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/blob/noetic-devel/compressed_image_transport/src/compressed_publisher.cpp#L137) shows the compression is done using OpenCV's imencode:

```
cv::imencode(".jpg", cv_ptr->image, compressed.data, params)
```

OpenCV is able to use *libjpegturbo* only by building OpenCV from source code to incorporate libjpeg-turbo to OpenCV. This is described in [this tutorial](http://unanancyowen.com/en/opencv-with-libjpeg-turbo/).

Another option (maybe much simpler) would be to implement your own image transport plugin. Therefore you can orient on the existing one.